# Unable to Edit Excel documents in SharePoint using Firefox

Tags: firefox, microsoft-excel, internet-explorer, microsoft-excel-2007, sharepoint

I'm unable to edit Excel documents in SharePoint using Firefox. It tells me to switch to Internet Explorer. Is it not possible to use Firefox?

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab-2-ff-36/). It uses the IE engine to render pages that won't work in Firefox

Comment: IE Tab is unfortunately no longer around.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to say that it means what it says. You might want to try changing the user agent of the browser and using the Silverlight plugin, but if it's an ActiveX problem there is nothing you can do.